# Reading if button is hold

Tags: android, android-widget

I would like to increase the value of a variable constantly when a button is held down.

I'm using onClickListener but it only increase once when the button is click and released.
How do I determine if the button is being pressed and hold?

What I want is something like "while(ButtonIsBeingHold){count ++;}"

If there are any other methods please advice me on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using View.onClickListener, you could try using View.onTouchListener:

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

}
```

This will get fired for different types of touch events such as:

MotionEvent.TOUCH_UP and MotionEvent.TOUCH_DOWN.

You could set a flag for when the butotn is pressed (TOUCH_DOWN) and start increasing your counter and stop on TOUCH_UP. I would, however, advise not to use a while(true) loop and try to throttle the incrementing events being trigger. In this case, I would use a handler and pass messages to it at a constant rate. You can see how a handler like this is used for rendering and updating a game in the Snake sample project that comes with the Android SDK:

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Snake/index.html